# Are HAL and Swagger comparable?

Tags: javascript, json, api, reactjs, swagger

I like Swagger and all it's tools. I like HAL because I am able to create / follow a discoverable API. Are the two mutually exclusive or can I use swagger to implement a HAL discoverable API?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use swagger to describe links in responses, and there is value in that.  The swagger-ui explorer, however, will not automatically follow them (unless the response is a 301/302) so you will lose some of the "try-it-now" functionality.

Comment: Hey thanks for this. Any chance you could expand on this answer? What do you mean by try-it-now? What do you mean by swagger-ui explorer not following links?

Comment: If you look at an example of swagger-ui connecting to a server (such as http://petstore.swagger.io), you'll notice that executing an operation will return a payload, and display it in the UI.  If the payload contains a link to a resource--which is typical in a HAL resource--it won't _follow_ the link, it'll just display what it sees in the response.